# TYPO3 Extbase Repository Query Cache

Tags: caching, typo3, extbase

I have some questions about caching. Some preconditions first:

```
// query 1
$data1 = $this->myRepository->findByPid($myPid);
// query 2
$data2 = $this->myRepository->findOneByUid($myUid);
```

My questions:

1. If I execute query 2 several times in a script, the first call retrieves the data from the database, all other from the cache, without querying the database?
2. If I execute query 2 again later (e.g. in a second script) the data is retrieved again from the database (there is no persistent query cache, except I use the caching framework to store the results of this query)?
3. If I execute query 1 and then query 2 and query 1 contains the data for uid "$myUid", then the data for query 2 is retrieved from the cache?

Comment: You can check my answer to a different question, but with same logic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40126426/2070270

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is different for older and newer Typo3 versions. Afaik from Typo3 7.x onwards the cache is always used if you use the default repository queries. After retrieving a dataset from the database it is mapped to a domain object by the property mapper and if the object is already present in the cache it is returned instead.

In Typo3 6.x you would get two different objects for the same uid if you select it with `->findByUid` and for example as a controller argument

Comment: So your answer is, when using TYPO3 7: 1. yes? Questions 2 and 3 are not answered.

Comment: #3 - yes
#2 - what do you mean my a second script? If it is a new page request then the persistence cache is not used, only the page cache (default typo3 cache if your action is cachable). If you mean a second plugin that accesses the same repository then the cache will be used